# Why sometimes we should set jvm parameter -Xms and -Xmx to the same value? And what are the advantages about this?

Tags: java, jvm, jvm-arguments

If set them to different values, what's the advantages and disadvantages?

Comment: Initial and max. If you want the heap to be able to expand then use a higher max. If you don't, don't.

Comment: the advantage is that your process start with less memory.
the disadvantage is that once the program needs more memory it should go through the reallocation process (full collection + reallocation of more memory)

FYI: Oracle recommendation is to set -Xms value to the same value as -Xmx